# JavaScript inheritance - value undefined

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

Could somebody please explain why the firstName and lastName are undefined if I call the greet function?
Seems both are set correctly, so I don't really know what's wrong. And what should I do to fix it.

```
'use strict';

class Person {
    constructor() {
        this.firstName = 'James';
        this.lastName = 'Bond';
    }

    greet() {
        console.log(`Hello ${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}`);
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.salary = 1234;
    }
}

var employee = new Employee();

console.log(employee.firstName); //James
console.log(employee.lastName); //Bond
console.log(employee.salary); //1324

employee.greet(); //Hello undefined undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is super case-sensitive... `firstname != firstName`

You want:

```
console.log(`Hello ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`);
                               ^                ^
```

Comment: You're right, it's my fault. However I've read the code several times, I looked over this typo. Thanks a lot!